# R Shiny parse xml/html output to other UI

Tags: html, xml, r, shiny

Is there a way in R Shiny to parse the output I create with `renderText`,`renderPlot` or similar as raw xml/html code, so I can display the results in another UI than in `ui.R`?

[image: Everytime I change the input in ui.R, server.R calculates a new output and parses it in raw xml/html to my other UI. Would be nice if the result would also be displayed in ui.R but not mandatory]

Everytime I change the input in ui.R, server.R calculates a new output and parses it in raw xml/html to my other UI. Would be nice if the result would also be displayed in ui.R but not mandatory. Is there any way I can do so? I was playing around with the `XML` package but without satisfying results.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is. So you are getting results in your `ui.r`, but they are not in the right format? `renderText` doesn't work?

Comment: I think the problem is, that I don't really know how server and client are communicating in R Shiny. I can send an XML output with `renderText` and display it in `ui.R`, but I don't know how I should implement/parse the output of `renderText` in any other standard HTML website.